# How to fix this notice in Prestashop php file?

Tags: javascript, php, html, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am running a Prestashop site and a tiny stripe of text keeps dispaying on almost every page of my site (on top of the site) saying:

```
Notice: Undefined index: link_rewrite in /srv/http_mysitename/shop/modules/blockcms/BlockCMSModel.php on line 280
Notice: Undefined index: meta_title in /srv/http_mysitename/shop/modules/blockcms/BlockCMSModel.php on line 281
```

Here is my BlockCMSModel.php: http://codepen.io/Janos/pen/xExGww?editors=1000
→ lines 280 and 281 are:

```
        $content[$cmsCategory]['link'] = $context->link->getCMSLink((int)$ids[1], $query['link_rewrite']);
        $content[$cmsCategory]['meta_title'] = $query['meta_title'];
```

Please help me, I am not a programmer, I can handle only few html and css things. My office colleague gave me an advice on how to hide those notices but I would rather solve the entire problem.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the query in `$query = BlockCMSModel::getCMSMetaTitle($ids[1]);` is returning 0 rows so the `$query` is an empty `array()` which has no keys `link_rewrite` and `meta_title`.

Either fix this by adding a condition to handle what happens when query returns no rows

```
$query = BlockCMSModel::getCMSMetaTitle($ids[1]); //line 279
if (!$query) {
    // set empty strings when no rows are found in database or change this to
    // whatever you want to do when no rows are found
    $query['link_rewrite'] = '';
    $query['meta_title'] = '';
}
$content[$cmsCategory]['link'] = $context->link->getCMSLink((int)$ids[1], $query['link_rewrite']);
$content[$cmsCategory]['meta_title'] = $query['meta_title'];
```

or open file

`config/defines.inc.php`

and set `define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', false);`

Note that this setting will only hide the error outputs on your site.